# How can I make use of Event Delegation in a parent Svelte Component

Tags: event-handling, addeventlistener, svelte

In this example, if I click the Tutorial NavItem I get to the Tutorial
section. Here I forward an custom click event on every Nav Item, where I set the segment which has been clicked. In the app.svelte I pull in the NavItem component and set the segment to current, which tells the Nav Component (through Props), which segment is current and needs to be active.

My question is how Can i Make use of event Delegation, so the Nav Component listen for the click Event, so it doesn't feel so repetitiv

The minimal Example goes like that, I want the parent to handle the event?:
https://svelte.dev/repl/691e82ee168549c782b61c355e78cf9b?version=3.12.1

Here is a complex Ex. the Repl:
https://svelte.dev/repl/691e82ee168549c782b61c355e78cf9b?version=3.12.1

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include your [mcve] to the post

Comment: Thank you for the Tip I created an mre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you already use the `getContext` and `setContext` functionality. Instead of firing the event you can simply update that context:

**in NavItem.svelte**

```
function setSegment(){
    current.set(segment);
 }
```

Comment: Yeah thats it I somehow thought its read only for the get Context, but You can actually set it right there. Thank you.
I some how messed the repl up

Comment: Ok, here is the example with Your solution. Thxs alot 
https://svelte.dev/repl/691e82ee168549c782b61c355e78cf9b?version=3.12.1

Comment: Just one more thing, Can I handle events from the Parent node, like when you use current.target in vanilla js.
Let the Nav listen to a click event inside the Nav Component?

Comment: Also note that the proposed solution fits nicely for your specific issue, if you want the `Nav` component to fire an event on change, you would have to make the _current_ a writable (see https://svelte.dev/docs#writable) and attach a subscribe event to it that triggers the event.